# 会社 Gaisha or Kaisha?

Tags: meaning, kanji

According to wikipedia, 株式会社 seems to be pronounced "kabushiki gaisha" but the abbreviation is K.K. and "kabushiki kaisha" is supposedly accepted as well. What's the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30132/9831

Comment: It does. Thank you so much! I’m not sure how I missed it when searching